# How to remove product images in Magento 2

Tags: php, magento, magento2

I'm trying to remove product images in Magento 2, but all I can find is how to do it in Magento 1, which is very different.

**Here is what I found for Magento 1:**

```
if ($product->getId()){
    $mediaApi = Mage::getModel("catalog/product_attribute_media_api");
    $items = $mediaApi->items($product->getId());
    foreach($items as $item)
        $mediaApi->remove($product->getId(), $item['file']);
}
```

Anyone know how to accomplish this?

Answer (score 1):

Here we learn how to remove images from product.

```
$objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance(); // Instance of object manager
/*Remove Images From Product*/
$productId = 100; // Id of product
$product = $objectManager->create('Magento\Catalog\Model\Product')->load($productId);
$productRepository = $objectManager->create('Magento\Catalog\Api\ProductRepositoryInterface');
$existingMediaGalleryEntries = $product->getMediaGalleryEntries();
foreach ($existingMediaGalleryEntries as $key => $entry) {
    unset($existingMediaGalleryEntries[$key]);
}
$product->setMediaGalleryEntries($existingMediaGalleryEntries);
$productRepository->save($product);

/*Add Images To The Product*/
$imagePath = "sample.png"; // path of the image
$product->addImageToMediaGallery($imagePath, array('image', 'small_image', 'thumbnail'), false, false);
$product->save();
```

Ref. https://webkul.com/blog/remove-existing-images-and-add-new-image-to-magento-product-programmatically/

Comment: This script for adding images , not for removing image

Comment: It does not work.